# How to use maclaruin series of arctanx to calculate $\pi/4$ with 0,01 error?

Tags: analysis, taylor-expansion, error-function

question is how many should we expand the series to calculate $pi/4$?

maclaurin series of arctanx is 
$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\dfrac {\left( -1\right) ^{n}x^{2n+1}} {\left( 2n+1\right) }
$
and

$arctan(1)=\sum _{n=0}^{-\infty }\dfrac {\left( -1\right) ^{n}} {2n+1}=\dfrac {\pi } {4}
$

since the  reminder $R_{n}\left( x\right) =\dfrac {f^{n+1}\left( a\right) \left( x-a\right) ^{n+1}} {\left( n+1\right) !}
$

so $R_{n}\left( x\right)=\dfrac {1} {2\left( n+1\right) +1}=\dfrac {1} {2n+3}
$

error=$\left| \dfrac {1} {2n+3}\right| \leq 0,01
$

$ 2n+3\geq 100\\  n\geq \dfrac {97} {2}\Rightarrow n\geq 48$

is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of $|f^{(n+1)}(a)|\le 1$: Basically you are right, but it's $n\ge 49$.

Answer (score 0):

here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80

pi / 4 = 4 arctan(1/5) - arctan(1/239)

Comment: While this identity is indeed faster than the "Leibniz" approach, it is not relevant to the question.

Comment: put x=1/5 and 1/239 into the maclaurin series to get a faster answer

Comment: Yes, I agree that it works better...but the question is about approximating $\pi/4$ using the Maclaurin series for $\arctan(1)$.

Comment: @Ian - thanks for that, yes I misinterpreted his question!